# Python trigger hook when window is dragged and when window is released

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi, wmi, pywinauto

I am creating a tiling app in PySide2 and am using the win32api and pywinauto modules to register window movement. How do I create a hook to trigger when a window is being dragged and when a window is released?

Comment: Show us the code you're running so far.

Comment: It sounds like you are monitoring the location information of the current application. You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3781988/11128312).

Comment: It's not solvable by global Windows hooks (with pyHook), but it's technically possible using UI Automation API. We want to simplify this, but the feature implementation is frozen for now. You can try to learn the source code here in this pull request though: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/pull/701 (pretty large).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I ended up solving it by using win32api and monitering mouse clicks and window positions